# Assert in Regexp that a capturing group is present only once

Tags: php, regex

How would you do to assert that a capturing group is present only once and if not the case not match the whole sentence.

### Exemple :

I Have this url :

`/prenoms/recherche?text=&gender=girl&trend=&origin=&begin=&rarity=veryrare&length=&theme=7&end=`

And I don't want to match my url if there is 2 or more of the 3 possibilities (rarity|theme|trend) which are filed.

I tough of something like this :

`\/prenoms\/recherche?.*gender=(boy|girl)?.*(?<=rarity|theme|trend){1}=(\w+).*`

But it seems not possible to use quantifier on look-around.

[For testing purpose](https://regex101.com/r/2ckNg1/4)

Comment: Use this logic: [`^(?!.*((?<=[?&])(?:rarity|theme|trend)=).*(?!\1)(?-1)).*`](https://regex101.com/r/2ckNg1/6)

Comment: What language ?

Comment: PHP. I'm trying to use it @ctwheels but I guess I'm missing something :/

Comment: @Baldráni honestly, this is probably easier using `parse_url`

Comment: Hum possibly but i'm not sure I can use it. It's in a backoffice with a redirection module.

Comment: So you are trying to filter out urls that have 2 or three `rarity|theme|trend` query strings together?

Comment: @revo exactly !

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use built-in language functions rather than sticking with Regular Expressions. Basically you could parse both URL and query strings then count the intersection of two using `array_intersect()`:

```
$parseURL = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parseURL['query'], $queryStrings);
var_dump(count(array_intersect(array_keys($queryStrings), ['rarity', 'theme', 'trend'])) < 2);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/f5WqS)

But this is an answer to your question using RegEx:

```
\A.*?[?&](rarity|theme|trend)=(?=.*[?&](?1)=)(*COMMIT)(*F)|.*
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/tIp2Y)

I'm not sure but this may help too:

```
preg_match_all("~[^$](rarity|theme|trend)=~", $url, $matches);
var_dump(count($matches[1]) < 2);
```